# Tool to unscrew or remove the top portion of pressure regulating valve buried in ground

Tags: water-heater, water-pressure, regulator

The pressure regulating valves are typically installed right by water mains where I live (in Texas). They are buried 1 ft+ deep and a circular tube is installed for you to access the top screw to control water pressure. Recently I had to get one replaced at our old home. Spent close to $600 to replace old one with new one with help of a plumber.

As I was looking at the old and new pressure regulating valves, it looked like it has a PVC nut holding the spring, diaphragm. A picture is attached below.

I reached out to Watts tech support how to remove the top part so that I can replace guts with new guts using a rebuild kit or guts from new PRV. The guy suggested strap wrench. It is not an option as that doesn't work when the thing is buried in ground. You don't have space to maneuver turning it.

When the top is accessible through that tube, is there a tool like basin wrench that can clutch the hex or polygon nut of the black enclosure with a T handle at top to screw or unscrew it?

I am looking for ideas as this might happen with my current home in future. I want to be prepared and do it myself instead of digging the whole area up and touch many places than needed.

Appreciate pointers...

[image: PRV buried in ground]

[image: Watts LFN45 PRV]

Comment: For evidently less than 2 feet, a shovel is the tool of choice, after which you'll have better access to perform the rebuild without fooling around trying to get all the parts back in from the top of the tube. Limit the landscape plantings in the immediate area to annuals so they can be easily set aside and replanted when the work is done.

Comment: "is there a tool like basin wrench that can clutch the hex or polygon nut of the black enclosure with a T handle at top to screw or unscrew it". Yes, it's called a "basin wrench".

Comment: All this to avoid digging a 1 foot hole?

Comment: @user177013 I am rookie DIYer thinking that I can use a tool to unscrew and replace it. I ended up hiring a plumber to do it. They dug the area around it and it took two guys close to 1 hr to replace it with new one.

Comment: @videoguy Fair enough. Every DIY project should consider how much time it will take you.

Answer (score 0):

After closer observation,

I see a hex- type screw.

If you get the right size Drive nut and 1+ foot extension, you could unscrew it.

[image: valve]

and example fo drive nut
[image: drive]

Comment: A crow foot on an extension might be better.  Usually need to hold the screw when loosing/tightening the nut.  The nut is there to keep the screw from moving when tighten.